# How to move some of the X-axis labels above the Y-Axis line - EXCEL CHART

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Don't know how to get the X-axis label above the 0% Y-Axis line for the data that is negative values. Would like some help.

"pic of issue"

[image]

Comment: Dopes this work for you? Right-click on the axis and choose "Format Axis". Under "Labels", Choose either "High" or "Low" for the "Label Position"

Comment: I think you need to read my tutorial [Axis Labels That Don’t Block Plotted Data](https://peltiertech.com/axis-labels-dont-block-plotted-data/).